# What is the number $\;'c'\;$ that satisfies the conclusion of Rolle's theorem?

Tags: calculus

I have a problem

What is the number $\;'c'\;$ that satisfies the conclusion of Rolle's theorem for the function $$f(x)=(x^2-1)(x-2)\;\;\text{in}\;(1,\;2]$$
I've tried$$f'(x)= 3x^2-4x-1$$
we know,  to fiind 'c' $$f'(x)=0$$

So, $$\Rightarrow 3x^2-4x-1=0\\x=\dfrac {4+ \sqrt 4}{6}=1\\ x=\dfrac {4- \sqrt 4}{6}=0.33\\\therefore 1\notin(1,\;2]\\0.33\notin(1,\;2]$$
Please help. Where I've made misstake.

Comment: Have you substituted correctly for the quadratic formula? Seems wrong to me

Comment: $b^2-4ac =  (-4)^2 - 4(3)(-1) = 16 + 12 = 28$

Comment: You took the roots wrongly. You did $b^2+4ac$ instead of $b^2-4ac$.

Answer (score 1):

Solve quadratic equation correctly

$$3x^2-4x-1=0\\\Rightarrow \dfrac{4\pm\sqrt{16-4(3)(-1)}}{2(3)}\\\Rightarrow x=\dfrac {2\pm \sqrt 7}{3}\\\Rightarrow x=\dfrac {2+ \sqrt 7}{3}\;\text{and}\; x=\dfrac {2- \sqrt 7}{3}\\x=\dfrac {2+ \sqrt 7}{3}=1.55\in (1,\;2]\\ x=\dfrac {2- \sqrt 7}{3}=-.215\notin(1,\;2]$$

Hence, 
$\; c=\dfrac {2+ \sqrt 7}{3}\;$  satisfies the conclusion of [Rolle's theorem](http://www.actucation.com/calculus-1/application-of-derivative/mean-value-theorem-and-newton-raphson-method/rolles-theorem) for the given function.